# Batch inserts in Google Cloud Storage using the Java API?

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage, batch-insert

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/batch#batch-example-response) it's possible to batch inserts to the Google Cloud Storage service using HTTP. But how does one do that using the Java API? I cannot seem to find any documentation or examples of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/using-cloud-storage#prerequisites_and_setup), Google has provided a [Google Cloud Client Library](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-java/0.2.2/index.html). The [java doc](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-java/0.2.2/apidocs/index.html) of this library provides following sample code to make batch requests using a single `RPC` request:

```
StorageBatch batch = storage.batch();
 BlobId firstBlob = BlobId.of("bucket", "blob1"));
 BlobId secondBlob = BlobId.of("bucket", "blob2"));
 batch.delete(firstBlob).notify(new BatchResult.Callback<Boolean, StorageException>() {
   public void success(Boolean result) {
     // deleted successfully
   }

   public void error(StorageException exception) {
     // delete failed
   }
 });
 batch.update(BlobInfo.builder(secondBlob).contentType("text/plain").build());
 StorageBatchResult<Blob> result = batch.get(secondBlob);
 batch.submit();
 Blob blob = result.get(); // returns get result or throws StorageException
```

Comment: What confuses me is that it's under appengine. I have an app that is running outside of appengine.

Comment: It should work without appengine. The only benefit of running under appengine is that it makes authentication a bit easier.